# Bitbucket API connection using token

Tags: python, api, python-requests, bitbucket

I'm trying to connect to my bitbucket using API token generated in Bitbucket but the connection is returning HTTP 401 error when using Python requests module.
I need help to facilitate the completion of a task.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are using in the question

Comment: import requests
import json 
user_name = "l******"

access_token = "**********************************"

url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user"

#headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.get( url, auth=( user_name , access_token)) 
#r = requests.get( url, headers = { "Authorization" : "(user_name , access_token)"})
print(r.status_code) 
print(r.content)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you use basic authentication and then set your username and use the personal token as password.
Your username still required since the token associated with it

Comment: import requests
import json 
user_name = "l******"

access_token = "**********************************"

url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/user"

#headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}

r = requests.get( url, auth=( user_name , access_token)) 
#r = requests.get( url, headers = { "Authorization" : "(user_name , access_token)"})
print(r.status_code) 
print(r.content)

Comment: for bitbucket cloud you need to use your email as the username